# The relation of the Homogeneous Sobolev norm and general Sobolev norm

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm wondering if the inequality
$$
\left\| F\right\|_{\dot H^k(\mathbb R^n)} \le C\left\| f\right\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)} \left\| f\right\|_{\dot H^k(\mathbb R^n)}
$$
holds for $k\in[0,10]$ then
$$
\left\| F\right\|_{H^k(\mathbb R^n)} \le C\left\| f\right\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)} \left\| f\right\|_{H^k(\mathbb R^n)}
$$
holds for $k\in[0,10]$, where $\dot H^k$ denotes the homogeneous Sobolev norm and $H^k$ denotes the Sobolev norm of order $k$.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the formula $\|f\|_{H^k}^2 = \sum_{j=0}^k \|f\|_{\dot H^j}^2$?